# Coloured output when tailing php error log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, tail, error-logging

I'm trying to find a way (through escape characters or software) to display coloured lines in my php error log.

Right now I'm reading from them (live) with

`tail -n 50 -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

which is great but I'd love to be able to `error_log()` certain lines to be red, for example, flag an authentication error. Is there any way to do this?

I'm using PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a little Perl script that changes the colors of text matching a user defined regular expression. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Getopt::Std;
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor; 

my %opts;
getopts('hic:l:',\%opts);
    if ($opts{h}){
      print<<EoF; 
Use -l to specify the pattern(s) to highlight. To specify more than one 
pattern use commas. 

-l : A Perl regular expression to be colored. Multiple expressions can be
     passed as comma separated values: -l foo,bar,baz
-i : makes the search case sensitive
-c : comma separated list of colors;

EoF
      exit(0);
    }

my $case_sensitive=$opts{i}||undef;
my @color=('bold red','bold blue', 'bold yellow', 'bold green', 
           'bold magenta', 'bold cyan', 'yellow on_magenta', 
           'bright_white on_red', 'bright_yellow on_red', 'white on_black');
if ($opts{c}) {
   @color=split(/,/,$opts{c});
}
my @patterns;
if($opts{l}){
     @patterns=split(/,/,$opts{l});
}
else{
    $patterns[0]='\*';
}

# Setting $| to non-zero forces a flush right away and after 
# every write or print on the currently selected output channel. 
$|=1;

while (my $line=<>) 
{ 
    for (my $c=0; $c<=$#patterns; $c++){
    if($case_sensitive){
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/){
           $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ge;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($line=~/$patterns[$c]/i){
          $line=~s/($patterns[$c])/color("$color[$c]").$1.color("reset")/ige;
        }
      }
    }
    print STDOUT $line;
}
```

If you save it as `color` in a directory that is in your `$PATH` and make it executable (`chmod +x /usr/bin/color`), you can color lines from your error log like this:

```
tail -f -n 50 /var/log/apache2/error.log | color -l "\[error\]","\[notice\]"
```

As written, the script has predefined colors for 10 different patterns, so giving it a comma separated list as I have in the example above will color each of the patterns matched in a different color.

[image]

Comment: +1 for a great script/answer. I would love to add another +1 for properly invoking perl via env.

Comment: Hope you didn't write this just for the question :P Thanks, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [@terdon's fancy script](https://superuser.com/a/615050/195224) with multiple colors, here is a more simple possibility -- given you are satisfied with only one color (red):

```
tail -n 50 -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep --color -P 'error|'
```

- `--color` obviously tells `grep` to color its output
- `-P` activates [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)
- the only tricky part is `|`: This is the logical OR, so `foo|bar` matches either "foo" *or* "bar". Here the regex is closed right after this operator, so it matches the empty string. That way lines *without* "error" simply get printed (without any coloring)

*Note:* Probably not all versions of `grep` support both options, `--color` and `-P`, but with a recent *GNU grep* it should work (tested with GNU grep 2.6.3).

Comment: +1 for the `|`, what a clever idea. I had toyed with using `grep` for this but thought I could only select matching lines.

Comment: @terdon: Thanks, but it was [you who taught me](http://superuser.com/questions/602766/filter-file-when-a-column-is-in-whitelist/602785#comment743647_602785) about the empty string in perl `:)`

Comment: Perhaps, but it was you who thought f this application :)

Answer (score 4):

[sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) can be used for this.

apache-log-error.sed (copy and paste)

```
s/\[notice\]/[33m&[30m/
s/\[error\].*/[31m&[30m/
```

Run with:

```
cat error.log | sed -f apache-log-error.sed
```

You can remove the `.*` after `\[error\]` if you don't want the whole line colored.

If you want to do this on the command line you can use

```
cat error.log | sed -e 's/\[notice\]/\'$'\033[33m&\033[30m/' -e 's/\[error\].*/\'$'\033[31m&\033[30m/'
```

This can be turned into an alias or a shell script for convenience.

In the first example, typing ^[[33m into vim requires you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Escape</kbd> to embed ascii value 27 (shown here as "^[") in the file.  "[33m" can be typed in normally.  In the second example, '$'\033 is something you type normally, and bash translates that into the ascii value 27.